# How to use current user in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I'm trying to create a website with rails (6.0.0). i'm using devise library for users sign-up and sign-in system. now my questions is "How to use current user's id for creating the post (user_id is required in post model)."

this is my `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`

```
def create   
   @post = Post.new(post_params)   
   if @post.save   
     flash[:notice] = 'post added!'   
     redirect_to 'posts'   
   else   
     flash[:error] = 'Failed to edit post!'   
     render :new   
   end   
end   

def post_params   
   params.require(:post).permit(:name, :picture, :user_id, :description)   
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)` so activerecord sets the proper user_id.

Answer (score 2):

In devise, you can use the helper `current_user` to get the logged user. With this helper, you will access the User (or your model), so you can use `current_user.id` to get the logged user id.